# With react-redux, how to know when a form submission is complete and load the next component?

Tags: react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a  [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) form that when you submit the form calls this function:

```
  handleSubmit(data) {
    this.props.actions.createUserPosition(data);
    this.props.nextStep();
  }
```

From the component above's parent, this is how nextStep() works:

```
  nextStep(props) {
    this.setState({
      step : this.state.step + 1
    })
  }

  showStep(props) {
    const {history} = this.props

    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return <WorkPlacePage history={history}
                              nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)} />
      case 2:
        return <SkillPage history={history}
                          nextStep={this.nextStep.bind(this)} />
      default:
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Case: Default</h1>
          </div>
        );
    }
  }
```

The problem I'm having is when nextStep() is called, the `SkillPage` component is rendering without the `state` change made in the store from the handleSubmit createUserPosition method.

How can I know when the handleSubmit server/Redux store update is done, and then perform nextStep()?

### Updated with Thunk

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import userPositionsApi from '../api/UserPositionsApi';

export function createUserPositionSuccess(user_position) {
  return {type: types.CREATE_USERPOSITION_SUCCESS, user_position};
}

export function loadUserPositionSuccess(user_positions) {
  return {type: types.LOAD_USERPOSITION_SUCCESS, user_positions};
}

export function loadUserPositions() {
  // console.log('actions: loadUserPosition')
  return function(dispatch) {
    return userPositionsApi.getAllUserPositions().then(user_positions => {
      dispatch(loadUserPositionSuccess(user_positions));
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}

export function createUserPosition(user_position) {
  // console.log('actions: createUserPosition')
  return function (dispatch) {
    return userPositionsApi.createUserPosition(user_position).then(responseUserPosition => {
      dispatch(createUserPositionSuccess(responseUserPosition));
      return responseUserPosition;
    }).catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make the question more helpful?

Comment: I presume when you mention about the "server/redux store" you mean that your function "createUserPosition" is an async action that calls an API? If so, you will need that function to return a promise. Based on that promise you can use the .then and .catch to deal with its success or failure.

Comment: @ChrisCousins correct. I'm using thunk. I don't understand how to deal with it how to deal with the success or failure how do I communicate that to my container so it knows which component to render and when?

Comment: Please post the thunk you're using (createUserPosition). It *should* be returning a promise.

Comment: @ChrisCousins thanks for the comment. Just updated the question with the thunk I'm using for createUserPosition... Is this what you were looking for? Any ideas? Thanks!